# Allocate AVFrame for sws_scale()

Tags: ffmpeg, libav, libavcodec

Trying to write program which uses `libav` to extract raw pixel data (~BMP) from arbitrary video. Everything goes well except `sws_scale()` failing to convert `AVFrame` to RGB24.

I formulated minimal example of it where `AVFrame` is being created and initialized with 4 different methods found on internet: https://github.com/SlavMFM/libav_bmp_example - all of them fail in different ways. How can I fix it so `sws_scale()` does the convertion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't use `avcodec_decode_video2`. Use `avcodec_send_packet` and `avcodec_receive_frame`

second, Don't call `av_frame_get_buffer` on source Just allocate it with `av_frame_alloc`, `avcodec_receive_frame` will set up the rest

Then allocate a destination frame frame like:

```
AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
frame->format = whatever;
frame->width = w;
frame->height = h;
av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 32);
```

Comment: It succeeds now! Frame successfully allocates and `sws_scale()` doesn't complain anymore. The problem now is that `sws_scale()` doesn't convert image to BMP - it just passes it on intact, so it's still in YUV420P format, I guess: https://github.com/SlavMFM/libav_bmp_example/blob/master/2.bmp . Also I reworked the example to using `avcodec_receive_frame()` instead of `avcodec_decode_video2()` - no more **deprecation warning**s ^^